# Designing in XML or Coding UI.Which is better?

Tags: android

I have a small doubt
Which is the best way to design UI for Android 
Coding or Desinging in XML?

Which is better in performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From personal experience I would say that the performance difference between the two is negligible. However, use XML for the pure reason that it it more maintainable. 
This way you can create your layouts in a way that can be easily recognized and edit by other possible future developers (or even yourself later).

Anything you can do layout wise in code you can do in XML and if you need to add more advanced features you can still reference elements in the XML in code using `findViewById(R.id.ELEMENT_NAME);`

Answer (score 3):

Performance will be similar (the XML version will be a little bit slower to load but not noticeably.) But by using XML you get automatic support of runtime configuration changes. You can easily provide different layouts for different resolutions, orientations, languages, etc. It is recommended to use XML to define your UIs as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would say it's a very good question and I will say that it's XML which will be easier to use rather than code for the following reasons:

1. Designing layout using XML gives you a better look and feel for the application;
2. If you want to make an application which has property of seamlessness XML is the
   best way to do it;
3. It is much quicker and faster to design UI with XML than with code.